# Type script на находит локальный CSS модуль

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, webpack

Всем доброго дня

Перевожу React приложение на Type Script и во всех компонентах в import выдает ошибку

> Cannot find module './.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations

Как можно решить данную проблему не трогая Webpack(если можно)?

Comment: Попробуйте где-то на уровне `index.js` объявить `declare module '*.css';`

Comment: Все равно ругается